# Implementing High charts with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, highcharts

I have been trying to implement the use of high chart with codeigniter. So far I have tried following the steps at http://blueflame-software.com/using-highcharts-with-codeigniter/ , but each time I preview my work in the browser, I get an empty screen with no result. Please can some on help me to resolve it. I have been on this for sometime now, yet no positive result

Also I have tried some of the steps shown here on stack overflow, yet nothing still display on the browser when I view it.

Below is my code:

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement it as a **library**. But the steps are quite larger to describe here.

Here are some links
https://blueflame-software.com/using-highcharts-with-codeigniter/
https://blueflame-software.com/using-highcharts-with-codeigniter/